# How to import OR-Tools on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, or-tools

I am trying to implement Google's OR-Tools as mentioned in their TSP example in Android Studio.

However, I can't seem to find out how to import OR tools, and I have no experience on implementing anything outside of writing my own code.

I cannot seem to find any examples of doing this as well. Would appreciate if anyone could explain how to do this, preferably in an easy to understand manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR-Tools uses native C++ libraries for the solver.
We do not provide arm based compilation. So, at best, you will be able to use it an x64 based architectures.

We recommend using a android client/server based architecture.